# Printer do not print, job just disappears

Tags: printing, network-printer, brother-printer, print-drivers

I have a Brother MFC-5890CN printer attached via LAN. It worked great until 2 days ago. From then, when I send a job it goes to job queue appears on printer queue but suddently in 5 seconds disappears without being printed and without any error (while the printer is online). From the PC cannto send any print, not a test page print or from any program… when sending the job, the printer display gets ON for a while though….

From the printer everything works, alignments, test print, etc…

I have removed printer, reinstalled windows drivers, tested to print via USB, updated printer firmware, but the issue remains.

My OS is:
Windows 10 Pro
Version : 1903
OS Version: 18362.900

Any idea?

Comment: Which OS? And which build? There is a known issue with recent Windows 10 builds where jobs disappear. It's fixed in build 2004. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/release-information/status-windows-10-2004

Comment: I have Windows 10 Pro
Version : 1903
OS Version: 18362.900

Comment: Thanks! I'll upgrade to 2004

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue in a recent build of Windows 10, and is resolved in build 2004. See https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/release-information/status-windows-10-2004

[image]